# Error when using Twitter Bootstrap .span12 in a .less file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

i want to use default bootstrap classes like `.span12` and `.row` in my own `style.less` but it shows error `.row is undefined`

```
.my-class{
  .span12; // returns error undefined
  // or .span(12);
}
```

is there any way to use them in a `.less` file? for example `.span(12)`.

Comment: i might be wrong, but from the documentation i would say, that you have to use the mixin makeColumn (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#mixins search for span)

Comment: yes, i should use .makeColumn, thank's!

Comment: @sdepold you should post the answer as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation, you have to use the mixin `makeColumn`. See the [relevant section](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#mixins) for further information. You might need to search for `span`.

Comment: I like to define

    `.row() {
        .makeRow();
    }

    .col(@columns: 1, @offset: 0) {
        .makeColumn(@columns, @offset);
    }`

Comment: Where is the relevant section located?

Comment: Seems that they have removed the section from the documentation :-/ Possibly because they added this editor: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables. However makeRow should still work.